# About Azure data factory pipeline to upload data to blob storage

Tags: azure

I want to upload data to blob storage with data factory pipeline My operation system is mac pro.
(Actually I just want to upload files to blob storage with data factory pipeline.........)

Q1
And when I new a linked service . I choose file system, but the host option which i input will be added a  "e://"
If this is only valid for windows???

Q2
As the below pic. what is thr  user name and password? It is my personal pc's? or some other name and password?

Q3

If  i choose "type" to FTP. It either can not connect to ftp service. I i need install some plugs? 
(I user other tools-----file zilla-----to connect the ftp service , it's ok.......)

Thanks and Best Regards!!!!

Comment: Why you choose ADF to upload files into Azure Blob Storage?

Comment: The customer proposed to use it

Comment: I'd suggest looking into the various tools available (such as the command-line Azure support in both the CLI and PowerShell) to look at file-copy options.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, uploading files from on-premises environment to Azure Blob Storage is your requirement.

Firstly,you could get idea of [Integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime) in the ADF. It has 3 types:

[image]

Surely, Self-hosted Integration Runtime need to be adopted with your situation.This is [features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#self-hosted-integration-runtime) of Self-Hosted IR.

Default IR is Azure IR.It is used between cloud environments.

[image]

Please follow this tutorial to create Self-Hosted IR.(need to install agent on your local environment) After that,you could configure FTP site to connect with your Azure Blob Storage in copy activity.

---

Update Answer:

Thanks for @David's comment. As you are using Mac Os, you could consider using other tools or methods to upload files. Such as using [CLI](https://www.google.com/search?q=azure%20cli%20for%20mac&rlz=1C1GCEU_zh-TWSG837SG837&oq=azure%20cli%20for%20mac&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.2575j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ([install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-macos?view=azure-cli-latest) for mac) , [Blob Storage SDK for mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=macos#run-the-sample) or [Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/).

Comment: Integration Runtime is Windows-specific. It won't work on a Mac (what the OP has).

Comment: thank u very much...but according the docs description , the IR is just support windows... if any other methods for mac?

Comment: @曾经被狼咬 - there are many ways to copy data to Azure blobs, including command-line tools. I'd suggest spending a bit of time looking into these.

Comment: @David Makogon thank u ! but the customers proposed to use pipeline.. so i don't know if the tools you said are valid for them. thank you all the same!    I will find a windows sever and do as Jay Gong said.

Comment: @曾经被狼咬 Hi,if my answer helps you,you could mark it  for others' reference. Thanks.